# Why my EF statement giving me error "Unable to create a constant value of type 'Anonymous type'. Only primitive types or enumeration ..."?

Tags: entity-framework

Why my following EF statement giving me error "Unable to create a constant value of type 'Anonymous type'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

```
  var listOfCustomData = dbContext.someEntity.Select(x => new
                        {
                            MyId = x.MyId,
                            YourId = x.MyId 
                        }).ToList();

                        var DataWithinNetworklist = dbContext.Users.Where(u =>
                            listOfCustomData.Any
                            (   x => x.MyId == u.MyId &&
                                x.YourId == u.YourId)
                            )
                            .Select(u => u.UserId)
                            .ToList();
```

Comment: EF can not infer the type of x in the second query, you cannot use anonymous in this context.

Comment: What can be the possible way to achieve the desire result.

Answer (score 0):

Define a class that acts like a proxy or flatted object for someEntity:

```
class someEntityProxy{
    public int MyId {get;set;}
    public int YourId {get;set;}
}

var listOfCustomData = dbContext.someEntity.Select(x => new someEntityProxy
{
        MyId = x.MyId,
        YourId = x.MyId 
}).ToList();
```

> EDIT:

Change the second query to something like the following, I have not tested this so you might get some syntax error:

```
var DataWithinNetworklist = dbContext.Users.Any( u=> listOfCustomData.Where(x => 
        x.MyId == u.MyId && x.YourId == u.YourId )
        .Select(u => u.UserId)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Do you get the same exception?

Comment: But here you are not using anonymous object anymore. Are you projecting to someEntityProxy? Note new someEntityProxy

Comment: Now error changed to System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Exp2.Models.ViewModel.PeopleEntityProxy'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.